# Sorting instances of an Object by Numeric values Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, object, web-scraping

I'm scraping a website for certain values like name, price, stock and rating and have been using the functions

```
    my_products.sort(key = lambda x: x.return_name())
    my_products.sort(key = lambda x: x.return_price())
    my_products.sort(key = lambda x: x.return_rating())
    my_products.sort(key = lambda x: x.return_stock())
```

to sort them.  It all works fine and dandy, except it doesn't sort the price numerically, it lists them like 1000, 1500, 20, 200, 2000, 2500.  Which isn't exactly what I'm looking for.  How can I change this sorting behavior?

The class for each product:

```
class Product():
__title = ""
__price = ""
__rating =""
__stock = ""

def __init__(self,title, price, rating, stock):
    self.__title = title
    self.__price = price
    self.__rating = rating
    self.__stock = stock

def toString(self):
    return "Title: {}\nPrice: {}\nRating: {}\nStock: {}\n".format(  self.__title,
                                                                    self.__price,
                                                                    self.__rating,
                                                                    self.__stock)

def return_price(self):
    return self.__price

def return_name(self):
    return self.__title

def return_rating(self):
    return self.__rating

def return_stock(self):
    return self.__stock
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you write it in your class, `price` is a string, then all prices will be compared like strings. 
You have two options:

1. Convert price into the sorting function : `my_products.sort(key = lambda x: float(x.return_price()))`.
   note that you can convert either by `int()` or `float()`
2. Declare price directly as a numeric (and don't change the sorting syntax):

   ```
   class Product():
       __title = ""
       __price = np.nan
       __rating =""
       __stock = ""

       def __init__(self,title, price, rating, stock):
           self.__title = title
           #---
           self.__price = price#if price is a numeric input
           #or convert to the right type if price is a string input
           self.__price = float(price)
           #---
           self.__rating = rating
           self.__stock = stock
   ```

In my opinion I would use the option 2 to stay coherent with the meaning of the values. Note that you should rewrite your functions accordingly to new types.
Maybe you could do the same with your ratings / stocks (if it is numeric too).

**EDIT - String comparison and sorting**
To compare string python convert characters into their ordinal equivalent then check int from left to right. So '1000' is lower than '20', see below:

```
print('1000 : %d' %sum(ord(i) for i in '1000'))
print('1500 : %d' %sum(ord(i) for i in '1500'))
print('20 : %d' %sum(ord(i) for i in '20'))

#output
1000 : 193
1500 : 198
20 : 98
```

Comment: Alright, I wasn't aware the sort worked on type of data as well as the value of it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. For the string comparison Python converts characters into their equivalent ordinal values and compares the integers from left to right (See update in my post).

Answer (score 2):

Just convert strings to numbers (e.g. `int` or `float`) in your key function:

```
my_products.sort(key = lambda x: float(x.return_price()))
```

You could also update the method so that it returns a number in the first place:

```
def return_price(self):
    return float(self.__price)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change this behaviour by making `price` a numerical value, not a string which forces that lexicographical sort which you currently have. It should normally be:

```
__price = 0
...
def __init__(self, title, price, rating, stock):
    self.__price = float(price)
```

OTOH, you can force the users to pass a numerical value for price, as opposed to doing the clean up in your class, by raising a `ValueError` for non-numericals passed as *price*.